How to sign <EncryptedAssertion> element using the STR-Transform algorithm in c#
In the SOAPEnvelope.

I wants to signed the xml element 'EncryptedAssertion'.
<EncryptedAssertion>
    <EncryptedData>....</EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>

using the below Transform algorithm (STR-Transform)
<Transform Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#STR-Transform">
    <o:TransformationParameters>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </o:TransformationParameters>
</Transform>

Whats kind of Transform class would be helpful here?
In C#, I only can see just the following Transform classes. Which i thinks none of these relates
to the STS-Transform.

How you will suggest to signed the "<EncryptedAssertion" element  using the SecurityTokenRequest-Transform?
Thanks in advance for any tips :)

The question relates more to the SignedXML object in c#.
